# How to get http response(success or fail) with Observable in angular 2?

Tags: angular

My code is

```
this.slimLoaderService.start();
return this.http.post(url, data, options)
    .map(this.getResult)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

i need to add a this.slimLoaderService.complete(); to stop the loader once i get  the http response.

Comment: You need to subscribe to really send the request. You'll write your slimLoaderService.stop() code in subscribe function.

Comment: add `.finally(() => this.slimLoaderService.complete())`.

Comment: @JBNizet cool it worked great . i am unaware of the finally method , i tried with do but got some problem with that , Thank you

Comment: @JBNizet Perhaps i need to change the question , please submit this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the finally() operator, which allows axecuting a function when the observable completes or errors:

```
.finally(() => this.slimLoaderService.complete())
```

Comment: Thank you for the very fast response :)